# How to open activity from background service's full screen intent notification Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

*Project min API KitKat(19), project target API Android 10(30)*

I am trying to do something to the effect of launching an activity from my background service.
I understand that launching an activity from a background service is explicitly impossible as of API 29.

However, would it be possible to create a full-screen intent notification and a broadcast receiver for that notification which automatically opens an activity from my app? Or, will the user still have to click on the full-screen notification before the activity could be launched?

If automatically launching an activity from a broadcast receiver in this way is possible, how would it be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open activity from the background by adding `"SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"` permission to the manifest and ask for user permission once when the app opened the first time by calling `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION));` somewhere in your app and granting permission to your app.

Comment: I will try that! Is there a place in settings the user needs to be rerouted to with my code or will the dialogue be opened by the android system when I put the permission in the manifest?

Comment: I added the permission and running this activity from my background without any luck: `Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        App.getContext().startActivity(startMain);` What else should I do?